# How to integrate Webradar with IBM WCM 8?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I have a requirement to integrate webradar with IBM WCM 8. I searched on net but didn't get any documentation or help link which describes the steps. Can anyone please help me in describing the steps or provide me a link on the same ? The link which discusses on this feature is- http://ephox.com/webradar

Answer (score 0):

Here is the download and the documentation links

Download from here

https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=05BDBC853494527B85257CA50009830C

Documentation is here

http://docs.ephox.com/display/WebRadar/Welcome